# How to check for Logs volume daily/monthly in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I want to check for daily/monthly log volume in Kibana.
I found a REST API query:

`GET /_cat/indices?v&pretty`

It shows me the size per index.
Is this possible to achieve volume monthly/daily? And how?

Comment: Do you need a one-time query or persistent visualization?

Comment: I need it for one time check.

Comment: I also tried to add parameters but, it seems that it's not changing the numbers: `GET /_cat/indices/_all?v&s=store.size&time=d`

Comment: You probably need a date histogram aggregation. What's your timestamp field name?